# Computer Vision: Calculate normalized value of descriptors

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, normalization, data-mining, pybrain

I am doing image classification project and i have made the corpus of features.

I want to normalize my features for the input of PyBrain between -1    to 1 I am using the following formula to normalize the features

```
Normalized value = (Value - Mean ) / Standard Deviation
```

but it is    giving me the normalized some values between -3 to 3 which is very    inaccurate.

I have 100 inputs in pybrain and 1 output of pybrain.

Comment: What you are doing is Center / Normalize => So after modification, the average is going to be 0 (center) and the standard deviation is going to be 1 (normalize). It's a very effective way to pre-process data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you used is that of standardization. It does *not* guarantee your values are in -1;1 but it rescales your data to have a mean of 0, and a standard deviation of 1 afterwards. But points can be more than 1x the standard deviation from the mean.

There are multiple options to bound your data.

1. Use a nonlinear function such as `tanh` (*very* popular in neural networks)
2. center, then rescale with `1/max(abs(dev))`
3. preserve 0, then rescale with `1/max(abs(dev))`
4. `2*(x-min)/(max-min) - 1`
5. standardize (as you did) but *truncate* values to -1;+1
6. ... many more

Answer (score 0):

In case of you have **positive** dataset, you can normalize your values using this formula

```
Normalized value = (Value / (0.5*Max_Value) )-1;
```

This is going to give you values with the range [-1,+1]

In case you have **positive and negative**:

```
 Normalized value = ((Normalized - Min_Value)/(Max_Value-Min_Value)-0.5)*2
```

Comment: I assumed that the input is positive.. my fault

Comment: That equation is incorrect and *can* return values much smaller than -1. Consider the inout data set [-100,1,2], for example. Or even worse: [-1,-2,-3,0]

Comment: Still not working right, afaict. -min instead of +min.

Comment: OK last time I answer something in hurry :D yes of course you are right

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
Mid_value = ( Max_value + Min_Value )/2
Max_difference = ( Max_value - Min_Value )/2;
Normalized_value = ( Value - Mid_value )/Max_difference;
```

The Normalized_value shall be within [-1,+1].